# Can you install multiple SSL certificates on IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, shared-hosting

Wondering what is the right way to install a UCC certificate on IIS? I have to request a UCC certificate from GoDaddy that allows up to 5 host names. The certificate they will provide will be a single certificate. So I am wondering if I have to install this certificate one-by-one on 5 of the 100 websites running on the IIS server or is it OK to just install it on the default website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the certificate to each website will not work. You just need to follow these instructions: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html to install the certificate to all the sites listed in the certificate (all on the same IP address).

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which certificate you're going to use for each web site. You don't specify what version of IIS you're using so it's not possible to give you exact instructions but this can also be changed by script.

You can, however, install the certificate in the server store only once and then select the same certificate for each web site. Remember, though, that you will need different IP or port for each of the domain that will accept SSL connections and that you will be unable to use host name mapping to distinguish between your webs.

since you mention that you have only 6 names in your certificate (a Subject.CN and 5 ADN) that means that you'll be able to use that same certificate without error for only 6 webs.